# Javascript: ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript

I dont understand what is happening here? any suggestions? This is happening on this line :-

```
var explode = gregorianDate.split('-');
```

Here is full function.

```
function updateCalendarDay(){ 
    if (document.getElementById('gregorianDateOutput') != null) {
       var gregorianDate = document.getElementById('gregorianDateOutput').value;
    }else{
       var gregorianDate = null;
    }
    if(gregorianDate != ""){
       var explode = gregorianDate.split('-');
       var year = explode[0];
       var month = explode[1];
       var day = explode[2];
       document.getElementById('month').value = month;
       document.getElementById('year').value = year;
       var ajax = new GLM.AJAX();
       var url='calendarAjax.php?month='+month+'&year='+year+'&day='+day;
       ajax.callPage(url, showSubscribeResult, "GET");
    }           
}
```

Comment: You have a string that can sometimes be `null`. Why not just have a string that can sometimes be blank? Then you won't have type issues.

Comment: shouldnot this line like this? ``if(document.getElementById('gregorianDateOutput').value != null``) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Jasper suggest you can assign empty String if not found:

```
var gregorianDate = "";
```

instead of

```
var gregorianDate = null;
```

**EDIT:**

Also you can check just by value:

```
if( gregorianDate )
```

And as Element `value` property always return's String you will get this only if value is present

Comment: I think type-checking in conditionals by default is a good idea.

Comment: That doesn't help. `null !== ""` is `true`. This simply checks if `gregorianDate` is not an empty string and `null` is not an empty string. In fact, when you compare against `null`, it doesn't matter if you use loose comparison or strict comparison.